# What is Thread locality

Tags: multithreading

What is thread locality?  I've been doing some research on a particular topic and thread locality has come a up a few times.  I haven't been able to find a clear definition of what's meant though.

Comment: What research have you done?  Can you quote some documentation that is confusing you?

Comment: Think you need to at least give some example sentences.

Comment: I've been doing research on program verification tools.  An example sentence would be "tool x helps programmers to check the correctness of thread locality in their programs"

Comment: Yours is a perfectly valid question, and Tilak gave a very good answer. IMHO..

Comment: @paulsm4 - I disagree.  Tilak's Answer is  about "thread locals", not "thread locality".

Comment: Then what would your definition be?  The way Tilak defined thread locality makes sense when considering what I have been looking at.

Comment: @paulsm4: Not familiar with the reopen queue, but does a third-party edit put a question in the reopen queue or something? Since all you did was add a newline. Also, calm down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread locality refers to [thread local storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Data marked as [threadlocal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx)/[threadstatic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx), is available as per thread copy to each thread accessing it. Any modification in data in one thread is isolated to any other thread.

Read [this](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_Thread-Local_Storage)  for details.

Comment: This is about thread locals, not thread locality.  If this was what the OP was asking about, then he has used the *wrong terminology*.

Comment: Indeed, in a comment he says: *"I've been doing research on program verification tools. An example sentence would be "tool x helps programmers to check the correctness of thread locality in their programs"*.  That kind of "thread locality" is nothing to do with thread locals.  I think that it is actually talking about what is often called "thread confinement"; e.g. when / whether an object is only observable by one thread for its entire lifetime.